# Node JS REST API image upload, how do i only upload jpg files and not png?

Tags: node.js, postman, express-fileupload

I am using express-fileupload as my middleware and POSTMAN as my API,
how do I only upload jpg images and not others file extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `mimetype` and throw an error if it isn't `.jpg`

For example:

```js
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (req.files.image.mimetype !== "jpg") {
    throw new Error("Only supports jpg file format");
  }
});
```